# Simplify selection of similar named columns by condition

Tags: r

The example code below is working but my question is how can I write this with less code and more elegant?

The point is I have columns with similar names. In this example I want to select all columns beginning with `B` and where all are with value `FALSE`.

```
set.seed(0)

df <- data.frame(A = sample(c(T, F), 100, replace=T),
                 B1 = sample(c(T, F), 100, replace=T),
                 B2 = sample(c(T, F), 100, replace=T),
                 B3 = sample(c(T, F), 100, replace=T))

n <- names(df)[startsWith(names(df), 'B')]

result <- df[df$B1 == FALSE & df$B2 == FALSE & df$B3 == FALSE, n]

print(result)
```

The result is

```
      B1    B2    B3
1  FALSE FALSE FALSE
26 FALSE FALSE FALSE
31 FALSE FALSE FALSE
35 FALSE FALSE FALSE
51 FALSE FALSE FALSE
66 FALSE FALSE FALSE
70 FALSE FALSE FALSE
84 FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

What I tried it this with unexpected results

```
df[df[,n] == FALSE, n]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With tidyverse :

```
df %>% select(matches("^B")) %>% filter_all(all_vars(.==FALSE))
```

or, if you want to check the row numbers :

```
df %>% mutate(id=row_number()) %>%                  # copy row number to new variable 
  select(id,matches("^B")) %>%                      # keeps id and variables beginning with B
  filter_at(vars(matches("^B")),                    # for variables beginning with B
            all_vars(.==FALSE))                     # keep rows where all are FALSE
#  id    B1    B2    B3
#1  1 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#2 26 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#3 31 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#4 35 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#5 51 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#6 66 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#7 70 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#8 84 FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: you can use `starts_with('B')` instead of `matches(^B)` as it's designed just for this use case.

Answer (score 3):

In base R, we can select the columns which start with "B" and then select rows whose sum is equal to 0 using `rowSums`.

```
inds <- grepl("^B", names(df))
df[rowSums(df[inds]) == 0, inds]

#      B1    B2    B3
#1  FALSE FALSE FALSE
#26 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#31 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#35 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#51 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#66 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#70 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#84 FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

---

Or as @snoram mentions , to make it more concise we can do

```
df[!rowSums(df[inds]), inds]
```

Comment: If concision matters: `df[!rowSums(df[inds]), inds]`

Comment: @Nicolas2 didn't run the `set.seed` function. Thanks, updated the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

A fast base-R alternative:

```
df[!do.call(pmax, df[n]), n]

       B1    B2    B3
1  FALSE FALSE FALSE
26 FALSE FALSE FALSE
31 FALSE FALSE FALSE
35 FALSE FALSE FALSE
51 FALSE FALSE FALSE
66 FALSE FALSE FALSE
70 FALSE FALSE FALSE
84 FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

**EDIT**

Staying closer to the original attempt you could do:

```
df[apply(df[n] == FALSE, 1, all), n] 
# or
df[apply(!df[n], 1, all), n]
```

Comment: Produces `Error in `[.data.frame`(df, !do.call(pmax, df[n]), n) : 
  objet 'n' introuvable`

Comment: @Nicolas2 you also have to define `n` as in the OP: `n <- names(df)[startsWith(names(df), 'B')]`

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

your data:

```
df <- data.frame(A = sample(c(T, F), 100, replace=T),
                 B1 = sample(c(T, F), 100, replace=T),
                 B2 = sample(c(T, F), 100, replace=T),
                 B3 = sample(c(T, F), 100, replace=T))
```

code:

```
df<- as.data.frame(!df[,grepl("^B",names(df))])

!df[apply(df,1,all),]
```

result:

```
#      B1    B2    B3
#1  FALSE FALSE FALSE
#26 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#31 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#35 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#51 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#66 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#70 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#84 FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can do

```
df[!Reduce(`|`, df[grep("^B", names(df))]),]
#       A    B1    B2    B3
#1  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#26  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#31  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#35  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#51 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#66 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#70  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#84  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```